# Issues mmaping the same file twice

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, mmap

I'm using a Raspberry Pi B+, and I'm trying to mmap two different sections of `/dev/mem` - the first to be able to set two pins' functions from location `0x2020 0004` (`0x04` bytes long), the other to manipulate the BSC Slave functions on the BCM2835 chip on the Pi from location `0x2021 4000` (`0x1C` bytes long).

```
static uint32_t * initMapMem(int fd, uint32_t addr, uint32_t len)
{
    return (uint32_t *) mmap((void*)0x0, len,
       PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
       MAP_SHARED|MAP_LOCKED,
       fd, addr);
}

int initialise(void) {
   int fd;

   fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) ;

   if (fd < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "This program needs root privileges.  Try using sudo.\n");
      return 1;
   }

   pinReg = initMapMem(fd, 0x20200004, 0x4);
   bscReg = initMapMem(fd, 0x20214000, 0x1C);

   close(fd);

   if (bscReg == MAP_FAILED)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Bad, mmap failed.\n");
      return 1;
   }
   if (pinReg == MAP_FAILED)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Bad, mmap failed.\n");
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

`initialise()` is called out of `main()`.  Stepping through the program with `gdb` I find that `bscReg` gets positioned right, but `pinReg` returns as `MAP_FAILED` (aka `0xFFFFFFFF`) with `errno` set to `EINVAL`.  Doesn't matter which way it's done, either - `pinReg` always finds itself as `MAP_FAILED` when `mmap`ed first or second.

How do I get `pinReg` to a valid value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `mmap()` is failing because the offset you're trying to map (`0x20200004`) isn't page-aligned. Create a mapping at `0x20200000` with a size of at least 8, then write to it at an offset of `0x4`.

Comment: Aaah.  That's why it's failing.  I thought I was being coy by only mapping what I needed.  I ended up mapping `0x0`, offset `0x2020000`, length `0x8` so I could still use the existing `initMapMem` method - works regardless.  Thanks for the catch!  (Would have helped if I knew what the RasPi's memory page size was...)  I'll accept it as answer soon as the site lets me.

Comment: Memory page size is 4K on almost all architectures, including ARM.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` will get you the page size too (though it's unlikely to change in this case).

Comment: @Ulfalizer Indeed, it's effectively a constant for any given architecture. Increasing it would be an ABI-breaking change, as it would make sections in existing binaries no longer page-aligned.

Comment: @duskwuff: I meant in the sense that this is device-specific code that isn't likely to be ported to other architectures. :)